# How to convert this PHP code to Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have been recently trying to convert a calendar I wrote to Javascript. Sorry, I asked a question here before, but I should have included this one in that one.

The procedure I followed to get the code was: to go through the PHP line by line, and convert everything to the equivalent syntax in Javascript. Instead of using POST to send information to the page in PHP, I call the calendar function using onclick links. Instead of using array_search I used indexOf (etc, etc). You get the picture.

In order to properly convert the code to Javascript, what else would I need to do? I'm not looking for anyone to do my homework for me. The calendar runs fine in PHP, and I think I've substituted all the necessary functions (such as indexOf for array_search and so on). The javascript code is identically equivalent to the PHP program:

PHP: http://codepad.org/87T2EFW9

Javascript: http://codepad.org/it10aljf

It shows October incorrectly, with just a previous link. Run it for yourself to see what I mean.

What kind of advice would you give me from here? Some folks have suggested to use JSHint, but it's giving me a lot of errors which I think aren't really necessary (obviously, I have declared variables multiple times, but nothing that would break the program). Are there any useful procedures I should undertake? Maybe I should start again, and go through it line by line, as thoroughly as possible? What do you guys do when porting (crappy, or noncrappy) code?

I see someone here has voted me down for asking this question, have I done something wrong? Should I not bother at all to ask?

Comment: I just wanted to update this: actually, there was absolutely nothing wrong with the code I ported - it was javascript. When I used the get day function, I assumed that like PHP, the function returned days in the correct order (eg Monday to Sunday). This was omitted from a page I was using (on w3schools), and because of that I might have spent a day or two agonizing over what went wrong. When porting, don't assume functions work exactly the same way as the language you were using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize this doesn't answer your question directly, but I would suggest rewriting the javascript version from scratch instead of porting it from php. JS has a very powerful Date object which does all date stuff for you (days in month, leap years etc). So the most of your php code is not needed in javascript.

For example, this is how you can find out days and DOWs in a given month using Date object:

```
var month = 10;
var year = 2011;

// this is the first of the month
var date = new Date(year, month - 1, 1);
// while we are in this month... 
while (date.getMonth() == month - 1) { 
    // print the date...
    document.write("date=" + d + " dow=" + d.getDay() + " day=" + d.getDate() + "<br>"); 
    // ...and goto the next day
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1); 
)
```